# Convert from DataFrame to JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector>

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to implement LDA algorithm using apache spark with Java API. Method LDA().run() accept parameter JavaPairRDD documents. 
I have use scala for create RDD[(Long, Vector)] follow:

```
val countVectors = cvModel.transform(filteredTokens)
    .select("docId", "features")
    .map { case Row(docId: Long, countVector: Vector) => (docId, countVector) }
    .cache()
```

And then input into LDA:

```
lda.run(countVectors)
```

But in Java API, I have CountVectorizerModel by using follow code:

```
CountVectorizerModel cvModel = new CountVectorizer()
        .setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("features")
        .setVocabSize(vocabSize).fit(filteredTokens);
```

look like that:

```
(0,(22,[0,8,9,10,14,16,18],
[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]))
(1,(22,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,15,17,19,20,21],
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]))
```

What should I do if I want to transform from cvModel into JavaPairRDD countVectors?
I have try this:

```
JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector> countVectors = cvModel.transform(filteredTokens)
          .select("docId", "features").toJavaRDD()
          .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Long, Vector>() {
            public Tuple2<Long, Vector> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<Long, Vector>(Long.parseLong(row.getString(0)), Vectors.dense(row.getDouble(1)));
            }
          }).cache();
```

But it does not work. I got exception when try:

```
Vectors.dense(row.getDouble(1))
```

So, If you have any ideal for convert from DataFrame cvModel into JavaPairRDD please tell me.

I am using Spark and MLlib 1.5.1, and Java8

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks
Here is exception log file when I try to convert from DataFrame into JavaPairRDD

```
15/10/25 10:03:07 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0     (TID 6)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to      java.lang.String
at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getString(Row.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getString(rows.scala:191)
at UIT_LDA_ONLINE.LDAOnline$2.call(LDAOnline.java:88)
at UIT_LDA_ONLINE.LDAOnline$2.call(LDAOnline.java:1)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1030)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1030)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/10/25 10:03:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 6, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getString(Row.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getString(rows.scala:191)
at UIT_LDA_ONLINE.LDAOnline$2.call(LDAOnline.java:88)
at UIT_LDA_ONLINE.LDAOnline$2.call(LDAOnline.java:1)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1030)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1030)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Protip: _it does not work_ is not a good description of the problem :)

Comment: Thank you, I will description about exception :)

Comment: OK, so we are going somewhere but we are not there yet. Exceptions  usually provide quite a lot of informations. What is the type of the exception, which part exactly caused it and so on.  All of that is there to guide not fill the screen. Also you're missing right parenthesis in the edit.

Comment: @zero323 you are very patient! ;)

Comment: @eliasah Call it an investment :) There is non-zero chance one day someone from here will be your coworker and even if not, it is always more fun to answer interesting and well crafted questions.

Comment: @zero323 I admire you man! You are right.

Comment: Many thank to @eliasah and zero323 :)

Comment: You are welcome! You can valid the answer and up-vote if you consider the answer to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we have the error stack, here is the error:

You are trying to get a string from the row whereas your fields is a Long so you'll need to replace `row.getString(0)` by `row.getLong(0)` for starters.

Once you correct this, you'll run into other errors from the same type but on different levels, which I can point out with information given but you'll be able to solve them if you apply the following:

The row getters are specific for each field type, you'll need to use the correct get method.

To know the method you need to use if you are not sure, you can use the `printSchema` method on your DataFrame to check the types of each field and then you can all the type conversion described in the official documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).