# How do I use StopWordsRemover to transform a Dataframe of json objects?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I am using MLlib and Spark 1.5.1. Input type must be ArrayType(StringType) but got StringType. What is wrong with my code?

```
StopWordsRemover remover = new StopWordsRemover()
                       .setInputCol("text")
                       .setOutputCol("filtered");

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("file:///home/ec2-user/spark_apps/article.json");

System.out.println("***DATAFRAME SCHEMA: " + df.schema());

DataFrame filteredTokens = remover.transform(df);
filteredTokens.show();
```

OUTPUT:

```
***DATAFRAME SCHEMA: StructType(StructField(doc_id,LongType,true), StructField(image,StringType,true), StructField(link_title,StringType,true), StructField(sentiment_polarity,DoubleType,true), StructField(sentiment_subjectivity,DoubleType,true), StructField(text,StringType,true), StructField(url,StringType,true))
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Input type must be ArrayType(StringType) but got StringType.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.transformSchema(StopWordsRemover.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.transform(StopWordsRemover.scala:129)
    at com.bah.ossem.spark.topic.LDACountVectorizer.main(LDACountVectorizer.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

article.json (1st row)

```
    {"doc_id": 11, "sentiment_polarity": 0.223, "link_title": "Donald Trump will live-tweet 's Democratic Debate - Politics.com", "sentiment_subjectivity": 0.594, "url": "https://www.cnn.com/...", "text": "Watch the first Democratic presidential debate Tuesday...", "image": "http://i2.cdn.turner.com..."}
```

EDIT: Implemented zero323's scala code in java and it works great. Thanks zero323!

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words");

StopWordsRemover remover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("filtered");

DataFrame jsondf = sqlContext.read().json("file:///home/ec2-user/spark_apps/article.json");

DataFrame wordsDataFrame = tokenizer.transform(jsondf);

DataFrame filteredTokens = remover.transform(wordsDataFrame);
filteredTokens.show();

CountVectorizerModel cvModel = new CountVectorizer()
        .setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("features")
        .setVocabSize(10).fit(filteredTokens);
cvModel.transform(filteredTokens).show();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, error message is rather self-explanatory. `StopWordsRemover` requires an `Array` of `String` as an input, not a `String`. It means you have to tokenize your data first. Using Scala API:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val tokenizer: Tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("tokens_raw")

val remover: StopWordsRemover = new StopWordsRemover()
  .setInputCol("tokens_raw")
  .setOutputCol("tokens")

val tokenized: DataFrame = tokenizer.transform(df)
val filtered: DataFrame = remover.transform(tokenized)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I thought the input would be a string of tokens. Duh, I get it now. It would be nice to see this in Java though because I went a round about way to tokenize the column while still including the other data in the dataframe that did not need to be tokenized.

Comment: Nevermind. I implemented the Java version exactly like your scala code above and it worked perfectly and the dataframe still retains everything. I thought the only column that would be in the tokenized dataframe would be the inputcol I specified. Thanks so much.

Comment: I see where you helped on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308586/convert-from-dataframe-to-javapairrddlong-vector Is this the correct way to create the corpus for the LDA?